# lsp-mode How to suppress function definitions for specific functions in python

Tags: lsp-mode

I am using `lsp` under Python. I have followed: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/installation/ for its installation.

```
(require 'lsp-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)
```

When I type `print(` automatically its description shown as below window:

[image]

Would it be possible to disable this option for selected functions such as `print()`,
hence I do not want to see its definition automatically.

Comment: I tried took a stub at it, and got a "kinda" working solution, but then my Emacs froze along with all code. Not gonna rewrite, because that was a dirty hack, and also `lsp-mode` folks should be ashamed of their `lsp-hover` function that accepts `contents` in what seems like a thousand of types! Anyway, your best bet is to create a report to lsp-mode and ask them to fix their `lsp-eldoc-hook`, which *(among other problems)* doesn't provide any way of extracting the docs. In my "hacky code" I had to modify `lsp-hover` instead, which I'm sure would break long-term due to using lsp-mode internals.

Comment: Can I try your `hacky code` code? Shoud I report to `lsp-mode` through their github issue page (https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues)? , I can write your points and link my question to them.

Comment: As I mentioned, I lost the code due to emacs getting frozen. But yes, it might be useful to create a report on the link you mention, in which you would describe your usecase, and also that there is a `lsp-eldoc-hook` which could've been used to implement your usecase, weren't it for the fact that: 1) the functions that this hook executes do not accept the new documentation as an argument, 2) the hook is a list of functions, but there's no way to make one of them stop the list execution *(which could be used by you to not execute that function that shows eldoc upon noticing "print" in docs)*.

Comment: I basically open a issue pasting or discussion: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/3038

Comment: They mentioned: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/how-to-turn-off/
I think you want to set `(setq lsp-eldoc-enable-hover nil)` and closed the issue.

Comment: You need to make it clear to them that you do not want to disable docs completely *(which setting the `lsp-eldoc-enable-hover` to nil does)*, but only for certain functions.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks. I have updated my issue. Hope they will response back

Comment: They linked to this issue asking is it related: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1223

Comment: @alper, what lsp server do you use? e.g ```pyright``` may display only the first line of your ```print()``` function, with some lsp-ui configuration (which is missing from your posting). This apply/shortens many other functions - could be a small improvement of actual situation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert on lsp and its options, but the following answer works for Spacemacs, where the popup window is created via `lsp-signature`.

In that case you could add a hook as follows:

```lisp
(defun lsp-signature-hook-function ()
  (setq lsp-signature-doc-lines
        (when (and lsp-signature-mode
                   (member (python-eldoc--get-symbol-at-point) '("print")))
          (lsp-signature-stop))))

(add-hook 'lsp-signature-mode-hook #'lsp-signature-hook-function)
```

And you can add more symbols to the list in the `member` form.

However, you might be interested to just set `lsp-signature-doc-lines` to 1 (see [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/fxqfs2/trouble_with_lspmode_and_eldoc/)). Subsequently, you can toggle between full and small size doc using `M-x lsp-signature-toggle-full-docs` (or by setting a value for `lsp-signature-doc-lines` by modifying the hook just mentioned).

Comment: Seems like it works, but I am seeing following warning text: `Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size` when I type `print(` and cursor waits; is this message normal? It does not show up all the time but it might makes `emacs` freeze for few seconds

Comment: That indeed is not clean behavior. So it seems to be caused by the `lsp-signature-function` calling `(lsp-signature-mode -1)` which again triggers the `lsp-hook-function`. So we should run the code in the condition only when `lsp-signature-mode` is `t`. I have updated the code snippet accordingly.

Comment: If I add another function name like `format` along with `print` , how could I add it? Should I recreate `lsp-signature-hook-function` function with different name?

Comment: As hinted in the answer, you should add the function names to the list in the `member` form, i.e. `'("print" "format")`.